# VueJS data() variable not working when adding data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a chat Application with VueJS, but when an user is sending a message it should be saved in an array. But this array is not getting any data. Here is my code:

The variable:

```
data() {
    return {
        messages: [],
    }
},
```

And the method I'm using:

```
sendMessage() {
    socket.emit('chat message', {name: this.name, message: this.message});
    this.message = '';
    socket.on('get message', function (msg) {
        this.messages += {
             "name":"" + msg.name + "",
             "message":"" + msg.message + "",
        };

        console.log(this.messages);
    });
}
```

But when the this.messages += function should add a json object. But in the Vue Tab in the browser it still says it's an empty array. What is going wrong here?

Comment: at your end of the `socket.on()` method add `.bind(this)` like this     `}.bind(this));`

Comment: Yess, that works @Ifaruki thank you! I didn't even know that..

Comment: usually people just use arrow functions, that means instead of this `function(msg) {` they write like this `(msg) => {` and it works too, but remember, arrow functions dont work in internet explorer. In that case its just 1 argument, so you can write it like this `msg => {`

Comment: Oh yea, then you don't need the bind function I see.